# Remove escape characters using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, escape-characters

I have input coming from pipe which contains special escape characters. For illustration, the stream looks like this:

```
printf "foo.bar\033[00m" > file
cat file
```

How can I remove the trailing `.bar\033[00m`?
I have tried the following, but that does not work:

```
cat file | sed 's/\.bar\033[00m//'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your file contains control characters such as

```
printf "foo.bar\033[00m" > file
```

then to remove the specific, single occurrence of `.bar\033[00m` write the following:

```
sed $'s/\.bar\033\[00m//'
```

To remove all kinds of escape sequences in the entire file:

```
sed $'s/\033\[[0-9;]*m//g'
```

The dollar-before-single-quoted-string (`$'some text'`) instructs the shell to apply ANSI C quoting to the string's content, like `printf` does.
This is required to produce the "escape" ASCII character (`0x1B`/`033`/...).

The character can also be produced via keyboard shortcuts (no `$'` necessary):

`sed 's/\.bar`<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>`\[00m//'`

After hitting <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> you should see `^[` on the screen, but not literal `^` and `[` (two characters), but one single control character.

---

*Original answer*

If you want in the output just `foo` then

```
printf '%s' 'foo.bar\033[00m' | sed 's/\.bar\\033\[00m//'
```

Notice that both `\` and `[` has to escaped by another `\`. Additionally I've added `'%s'` to `printf` to print the input characters as literal string, otherwise `\033[` could be interpreted as escape code followed by ANSI colour.

Comment: This is right. Adding '%s' is crucial in this case to avoid the special interpretation of `\033[`.

Comment: but the `printf` was just for illustration. As I said, my input is coming from pipe, not from `printf`. I need a solution which will work even without printf, such as: `cat file | sed 's/\.bar\\033\[00m//'`

Comment: And what is the problem? `sed 's/\.bar\\033\[00m//' file` should work just fine, doesn't it? Perhaps you should add `g` just before final `'` to replace all occurrences of such pattern.

Comment: I have used `cat file | sed ...` as an example to show why `printf` does not work. But I need to use `sed` not on file, but on input coming from pipe. Sorry if my example was confusing.

Comment: @MartinVegter From the edit of your question I believe that your file (or input stream) in fact doesn't have a string `\033[`, but rather control character. In such case write the following: `cat file  | sed 's/\.bar` `Ctrl-v` `ESC` `\[00m//'`. Here `Ctrl-v ESC` inputs escape control character, you should see `^[` on the screen. Please report if this is the case so I will modify the answer.

Comment: @jimmij - you are absolutely right. Now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `[` and `\` characters with a backslash:

```
printf '%s' "foo.bar\033[00m" | sed 's/\.bar\\033\[00m//'
```

Alternatively, if you want to remove everything after the dot character in the string:

```
printf "foo.bar\033[00m" | sed 's/\..*//'
```

Comment: this actually does not work. It does not remove anything.

Comment: @MartinVegter I edited the answer with `'%s'` inspired by the answer from jimmij for correctness.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this does not help me. My input is coming from pipe, not from `printf`. I need a sed command which will work like this: `cat file | sed 's/\.bar\\033\[00m//'`. The currect sed syntax does not work for this.

Comment: @MartinVegter Would this work: `cat file | sed 's/\.bar.*//'`

Comment: no. I don't want to remove any occurrence of `\.bar.*`. I only need to remove if it is at the end (followed by ANSI color code)

Comment: @MartinVegter Can you give this a shot: `cat -t file | sed 's/\.bar\^\[\[00m//'`